# How to open file saved in newest GarageBand on another computer with an older GarageBand

Tags: macos, ios, garageband

I have iPhone se2 with the latest GarageBand version.

I have an old MacBook 2010, El Capitan 10.11 with an older version of GarageBand (10.2.0). I can’t update the GarageBand on this MacBook because the OS doesn’t support it.

I’m willing to do a workaround for this. Converting to other different file types or paying if I must.

So how can I save the file in my phone and open it in my computer?

Comment: Great details, I made a minor edit. If solutions that cost money don’t work - you can always select the best answer that comes up. I hope this is easier than keynote, which is notoriously hard to back convert documents to older apps but at least has a web version of the app.

Comment: Is this just MIDI data, or are there audio loops?